# Append regular expression in SublimeText

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'm very new to regular expressions. I'm working on sublime text and I'm trying to replace all instances of some numbers formatted like this:

```
00:00:59
00:01:00
00:01:22
```

and so on.

Appending `:00` at the end si it will become 00:00:59:00

I used `[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}` and it finds all instances but I don't know how to append `:00` and replace all instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex works to find all occurences of these numbers. You click on the "Find" menu, then "Find". You enter the regex into the search box. Then you click on the "Find All" button in the lower right corner of your sublime text window.

Now you have multiple cursors, one for each occurence. You press your right-arrow key one time, so each cursor is at the end of its occurence. Then you type ":00" (without the quotation marks) and press ESC to remove all multiple cursors. That should work.

Comment: Or you use Wiktor Stribiżews answer and go directly to "Replace" and use a back-referencing regex. :-)

Comment: If the time strings are inside longer text, this solution won't help.

Comment: You saved me! Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

You may use

```
\b[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\b
```

as the regex and replace with `$0:00`. Here, `$0` is the backreference to the whole match.

[image]

V

[image]

The `\b` stand for word boundaries. If you need to avoid matching those timestamps that already have `:00` after it, you may consider using

```
(?<!\d:)\b\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\b(?!:\d)
```

The `(?<!\d:)` negative lookbehind will fail the match if the 2 digit substring  at the start is preceded with a digit + `:`, and the `(?!:\d)` negative lookahead will fail the match if the last 2 digits are followed with `:` + digit.

Comment: Note that `\d` in Sublime Text might match all Unicode digits, like `۰߀०০੦૦୦௦౦೦൦๐໐０`, so using `[0-9]` might be a safer option if you are after matching only ASCII digits.

Comment: Your answers are always right and providing a better solution than requested. Well done, Mr. Regex Master ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the search and replace tool of Sublime Text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Maj</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), with regex option activated (<kbd>.*</kbd> icon).

- Type `[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}` in "Find"
- Type `[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:00` in "Replace"
- Click Replace

[image]